# Is there a way to prevent scrolling of an iPython notebook, when calling 'mouse_scroll' event over a plot figure inside a cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, scroll, event-handling

Is there a way to prevent the entire notebook from scrolling, when scrolling over the figure to cycle through the images as shown in this example (and reproduced below): https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/image_slices_viewer.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


class IndexTracker:
    def __init__(self, ax, X):
        self.ax = ax
        ax.set_title('use scroll wheel to navigate images')

        self.X = X
        rows, cols, self.slices = X.shape
        self.ind = self.slices//2

        self.im = ax.imshow(self.X[:, :, self.ind])
        self.update()

    def on_scroll(self, event):
        print("%s %s" % (event.button, event.step))
        if event.button == 'up':
            self.ind = (self.ind + 1) % self.slices
        else:
            self.ind = (self.ind - 1) % self.slices
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.im.set_data(self.X[:, :, self.ind])
        self.ax.set_ylabel('slice %s' % self.ind)
        self.im.axes.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

def plot(X):
    mpl.rc('image', cmap='gray')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    plot = IndexTracker(ax, X)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', plot.scroll)

    plt.show()
```

On VS Code, using the,

```
%matplotlib widget
```

backend, I call the following function in a new code cell:

```
X = np.random.rand(20, 20, 40)
plot(X)
```

I am able to successfully generate an interactive plot in an iPython notebook, whereby scrolling over the figure scrolls through the "image slices". The scroll event only works if I hover the cursor over the plot/figure (as it should), ***however*** the entire notebook scrolls as well, thereby moving the cursor out of the figure frame.

Is there a way to prevent the notebook from scrolling when the cursor is hovering over a figure in the cell output?